# Can DirectShow Library be used with Qt?

Tags: qt, directshow

Can DirectShow Library be used with Qt? If yes, can somebody tell me how? Going through a lot of articles, I find that direct show is a great option when working with multimedia applications, yet I find that people have problems in using it with Qt.

Comment: Are you looking to play video files/streams from the web, or are you looking to record video from a webcam/camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually DirectShow is an COM api which is independent of any GUI. I don't understand which is a problem with a QT but you can get a handle of your QT based window and use it in your directshow wrappers without any problem. Also you could make an directshow app without any GUI just like a console app.

Comment: Can you give a brief tut? I am searching for a platform for making an application specific video player. Until now I have judged MFC + Directshow as the best combination......Is there a better combination?

Comment: No now but little bit later :).

Comment: @Aashish very good examples are available in Ms Platform SDK now it is Windows SDK. You can find them under Multimedia\DirectShow directory. Also you could obtain your window handle from your qt window and use it such as a normal HWND.

Answer (score 1):

First off, anything you will do in DirectShow with Qt will of course, work only on Windows. If you need it to run on other platforms besides windows you will need additional implementations for each platform.

Second, are you targeting the current release of Qt(4.8), or the upcoming 5.0 release?

For Qt 4.8 as already stated you can use Phonon for Video playback, it is simple to use, cross-platform, and works well. If you need to capture Video from a camera, you might try QtMultimediaKit http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility/multimedia.html. It has an interface very much like a cell phone camera.

If you decide you want to integrate DirectShow and Qt, you need to first learn DirectShow, and create a capture graph (See the DirectShow AMCap sample in the Microsoft DirectX 9.0 SDK (Summer 2004 release).   This requires a fair bit of knowledge of both QT and DirectShow. If you can stick with a prebuilt solution it will be far easier.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a video app then [QtPhonon](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/phonon-overview.html) can already uses directshow as a backend so you don't need to use it directly

Comment: I want to learn directshow in the first place. Creating GUI with MFC is cumbersome so I am looking at QT as an option. Can you tell me how to use directshow in qt (or any other) just as we do in MSVC?